# Display content is style box using css

Tags: css, animation, background-color

I have a content like below:

```
Scan Summary:

Total Found: 363
Total Dir: 153
Planned Sync Files: 210
Actual Synced: 210
Missing Synced Files: 0
```

My divs:

```php
<div class="page_summary">
  <div><h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;" class="total_found">Total Found: '.$totalFind.'</h3></div>
  <div><h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Dir: '.$totalIsDir.'</h3><br/></div>
  <div><h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Planned Sync Files: '.$totalShouldFind.'</h3></div>
  <div><h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Actual Synced: '.$totalResolved.'</h3><br/></div>
  <div><h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Missing Synced Files: '.$forOfor.'</h3><br/></div>
</div>
```

I want to display Total Found, Total Dir, Total Sync Files, Actual Synced Files and Missing Synced Files separately in style box separately, I searched a lot but did find the right match.

I want to display each item like dashboard.

Comment: what you expected can you screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
        <div class="page_summary">
        <div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;float:left;"><h3 class="total_found">Total Found: '.$totalFind.'</h3></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;float:left;"><h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">Total Dir: '.$totalIsDir.'</h3><br/></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;width: 33.33%;float:left;"><h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Planned Sync Files: '.$totalShouldFind.'</h3></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;width: 33.33%;float:left;"><h3 style="display: inline-block;width: 33%;">Actual Synced: '.$totalResolved.'</h3><br/></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;width: 33.33%;float:left;"><h3>Missing Synced Files: '.$forOfor.'</h3><br/></div>
        </div>
```